# Interactive graph visualisation for website

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to visualize a tree graph for my website/tool.

**Technical requirements:**

- support for modern browsers
- JavaScript (bonus points for TypeScript support or at least typings available)
- ideally free / one-time license payment

**Use-case:**

I'm working on a tool for a game, in which you produce resources from other resources using machines. Each machine can have a different speed and only produce some products, each product can be produced by one or more recipes, that can differ in speed, requirements for the recipe, etc. I'm doing a visualization of the whole production chain with calculating how many buildings/power does player need, etc.

I want the player to be able to dynamically add products, build the whole chain himself (while choosing recipes, buildings, etc.) and then save it in a browser/locally to have it available for later.

**Required features:**

- possibility to drag and drop nodes
- grid-like snapping (or at least initial generation of nodes in a grid)
- **HTML content in nodes** (I need a selectbox, some checkboxes, buttons, and some text/images, also the content will change over time) - this is the biggest limitation from what I've seen and googled
- ability to easily add/remove or show/hide nodes in the graph
- tooltips on edges (ideally image+text, but only text is sufficient as well)
- nice event system for handling clicking on nodes and html content inside

**Bonus features:**

- export/import of the whole thing (ideally json), so that I can reconstruct the graph later
- save the whole thing as image/pdf
- node can have border or without border and background (e.g. I want a node that's just html button)
- works well with Angular/AngularJS

Comment: can you tell us the name of the game? and if its 3D I can't comment yet so I have to use this.

Comment: @user29530 not sure how much is it related, but the game is Satisfactory (and even though the game is 3D, the visualization would be 2D)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find out-of-the-box components to do exactly what you want, but if you're looking for a code direction I would explore D3 with the use of "foreignObject" to embed HTML content in nodes.  D3 takes some time to master, but it will give you a lot of flexibility if you're going to be neck deep in coding interactive visualizations.

Here is an example of d3.hierarchy: 
https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree

Comment: yeah, I know there probably won't be exact solution, but considering how many js visualizatin libraries are there, I was wondering if there was a person that used a lib that could do similar stuff.
Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at that.